# Somethign similar to notification center?

Tags: software-recommendation, notification

Does software exist for ubuntu 14.04, which would notify you about facebook notifications, notify you about new emails and so on? If so, I would like to ask you to mention it.
Thanks.

Comment: Whats about https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is about indicator provided, following screenshot:

[image]